# How to create a solid rectangle border around the circle in UICollectionView Swift4+

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have tried the following but only creates a border around the circle but not a separate rectangle border.
[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSe7t.png)

```
cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

[I want to create a rectangle border as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWSge.png)

Comment: Can you include an image of what you currently have? It's hard to offer advice on just these three lines of code. What does "a border around the circle" mean? How are you adding the circle to your cell? How big is the cell relative to the circle?

Comment: @jrturton Included the image, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: You still need to supply more code, I think. Without knowing how you're creating the cell or adding the circle it's hard to know what is going on. For a standard cell adding a border will make it rectangular, so there's something happening to the cell's layer somewhere that is stopping that. Where is the circle coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

Have you tried?

```
cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

Comment: Oops I have accidentally added that 2nd line in while debugging. Yes, I have tried the following without the 2nd line and it only gives me a border around the circle as shown in the image.

Comment: @ctrlc_ctrlv_backspace hope it'll solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it'll work for you, but you can try to add an additional layer like that:

```
var rect = UIView()
var circle: CALayer?
override func loadView() {

// create view with border
    rect.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 300, height: 200)
    rect.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    rect.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    rect.layer.borderWidth = 2
    // add circle layer
    let circle = CALayer()
    circle = UIColor.red.cgColor
    // add circle layer on view with drawn border
    rect.layer.addSublayer(circle)
    view.addSubview(rect)
    circle = circle
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    // layout circle on your view
    let radius = min(rect.frame.width, rect.frame.height) * 0.5
    circle?.frame = CGRect(x: rect.bounds.width / 2 - radius / 2, y: rect.bounds.height / 2 - radius / 2, width: radius, height: radius)
    circle?.cornerRadius = radius / 2
}
```

But probably that's not the best option, maybe someone gives you better solution.

If it doesn't work for you, please, give more details of you problem.